# Groovy String concatenation problems with Jenkins

Tags: groovy, jenkins

I have a very simple Groovy script:

```
String test = "";
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4].each {test += it.toString()}
return test
```

When I enter and execute the script in the Jenkins script console, I get the expected result:

```
Result: 01234
```

However, when I execute the same script with curl, I get something else:

```
curl -X POST -d "script=$(cat test.groovy)" http://my/domain/jenkins/scriptText
Result: 4
```

Does anyone have an idea where such a difference could come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what's going wrong, but changing into explicit strings worked for me:

```
curl --show-error -d 'script=test="";[0,1,2,3,4].each{test = "${test}${it}"}; return test' http://my/domain/jenkins/scriptText
Result: 01234
```

Breaking your example down, and adding appropriate debug gave:

```
$ curl --show-error -d 'script=test="";[0,1,2,3,4].each{test += it.toString(); println test}; return test' http://my/domain/jenkins/scriptText
0
1
2
3
4
Result: 4
```

so the test wasn't being added to as a string. using GStrings directly sorted it out.

An alternative is to use inject, though it's still using gstrings:

```
$ curl --show-error -d 'script=test=[0,1,2,3,4].inject("") {acc, val -> "${acc}${val}"}; return test' http://my/domain/jenkins/scriptText
Result: 01234
```